# (C code) how would I pass my global variables between functions and return them when the main function needs them also?

Tags: c

(C code) how would I pass my global variables between functions and return them when the main function needs them also?  I've posted my code below for reference.  Of course, I also have a header file with my function prototypes in it as well but they only list variable types inside the closed brackets, not the variable names...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myheader.h"

char user_filename[150];
char user_filename2[150];
FILE *fp;
FILE *fp2;
int num_shift;

int main()
{
    int choice;     // main variables
    int option;


    char result;
    char ch;
    int offset;
    char character;
    int tmp;

    option = 0;
    num_shift = 0;
    strncpy(user_filename, "not set", sizeof("not set"));
    strncpy(user_filename2, "not set", sizeof("not set"));
    fp = NULL;
    fp2 = NULL;

    choice = menu(num_shift, user_filename, option);   // get user's first selection

    while(choice != QUIT)   //execute so long as choice is not equal to QUIT
    {
        switch(choice)
            {
                case INPUT_FILE:
                    input(user_filename);
                    break;
                case OUTPUT_FILE:
                    output();
                    break;
                case NUM_TO_SHIFT:
                    num_shift = shift(num_shift);
                    printf ("Shift by %d\n",num_shift);
                    break;
                case ENCODE:
                    encode(result, ch, num_shift, character);
                    break;
                case QUIT:
                    quit();
                    break;
                case REVIEW:
                    review (user_filename);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Oops! An invalid choice slipped through.  ");
                    printf("Please try again.\n");
            }
      choice = menu(num_shift, user_filename, 0); /* get user's subsequent selections */
    }

   quit();

}


int menu(int num_shift, char * user_filename, int option)
{
    printf("\nText Encoder Service\n\n");
    printf("1.\tEnter name of input file (currently '%s')\n", user_filename);
    printf("2.\tEnter name of output file (currently '%s')\n", user_filename2);
    printf("3.\tEnter number of characters data should be shifted (currently %d)\n", num_shift);
    printf("4.\tEncode the text\n");
    printf("5.\tReview the text in the input file\n");
    printf("\n0.\tQuit\n\n");
    printf("Make your selection: \n");


   while( (scanf(" %d", &option) != 1) /* non-numeric input */
          || (option < 0)               /* number too small */
          || (option > 5))              /* number too large */
   {
      fflush(stdin);                    /* clear bad data from buffer */
      printf("That selection isn't valid. Please try again.\n\n");
      printf("Your choice? ");
   }

    printf("Selecting %d\n\n", option);

    return option;
}

int input(char * user_filename)
{
    printf("Enter the filename of the file to encode:\n");
    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
    scanf("%s", user_filename);
    printf("Getting %s\n\n", user_filename);

    fp = fopen (user_filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nSorry, I'm unable to open the file (%s) for reading\n", user_filename);
        printf("Please try again.\n");
    }

    else
    {
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return INPUT_FILE;
}


int output()
{
    printf("Enter the filename of the output file to store encoded information:\n");
    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
    scanf("%s", user_filename2);
    printf("Opening File for Writing %s\n\n", user_filename2);

    fp2 = fopen (user_filename2, "w");

    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nSorry, I'm unable to open the file (%s) for writing\n", user_filename2);
        printf("Please try again.\n");
    } else
    {
        fclose(fp2);
    }


    //return user_filename;
    return INPUT_FILE;
}


int shift(int num_shift)
{
    printf("Enter the number of letters to shift for each character: \n");
    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_shift);
    printf("Setting shift value to: %d\n\n", num_shift);

    return num_shift;
}


int encode(char result, char ch, int offset, char character2)
{

    int character;

    printf("starting encoding with offset of %d\n", offset);

    fp = fopen(user_filename, "r");
    fp2 = fopen(user_filename2, "w+bc");

    if ((fp == NULL) || (fp2 == NULL))
    {
        printf ("File not found\n");
        return (0);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    printf("staring Encoding from %s to %s at position %ld\n", user_filename, user_filename2, ftell(fp));

    int i = 0;
    while(character = fgetc(fp))
    {
        if ( character == EOF)
        {
            //printf("%c",character);
            //fprintf(fp2,"%c",result);
            fclose(fp);
            fflush(fp2);
            fclose(fp2);
            return(0);
        }

        if (isalpha (character))
        {
            if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
            {
                result = character - 'a';
                result = (result + offset) % 26; // 26 letters in the alphabet
                result += 'a';
                if (result < 'a')
                {
                    result = 'z' - ('a' - result)+1;
                }

            } else if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z')
            {
                result = character - 'A';
                result = (result + offset) % 26; // 26 letters in the alphabet
                result += 'A';
                if (result < 'A')
                {
                    result = 'Z' - ('A' - result)+1;
                }
            }
            //printf("(%c)",result);
        } else
        {
            result = character;
            //printf("(%x)", result);
        }
        printf("%c",result);
        fprintf(fp2,"%c",result);

    }

    return 0;
}


void quit()
{
    //fclose(fp);
    //fclose(fp2);
    printf("Quiting...Bye!");
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}

int review(char * user_filename)
{
    char character;

    fp = fopen(user_filename, "r");

    printf("Showing text from %s file\n", user_filename);
    printf("----------BEGIN OF TEXT--------------\n");
    while(character = fgetc(fp))
    {
        if ( character == EOF)
        {
            printf("%c",character);
            printf("\n----------END OF TEXT--------------\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return(0);
        }
        printf("%c",character);
    }

}
```

Comment: `strncpy(user_filename, "not set", sizeof("not set"));` That's wrong.  The last parameter to `strncpy` is the max count of characters to copy, i.e., the size of the *destination* buffer.

Comment: Shy away from global variables whenever possible.

Comment: I'd like to not use global ones, but I'm not entirely sure how in this case. I am not quite grasping how to properly pass variables between main and other functions. The problem is, if I don't declare the variables as global, then main won't allow the compile to continue since the variables are not declared within main (but are in other functions. See what I mean, take a look at my program again... Other than this, the program works just fine as I expect it to. This is my final challenge...

Comment: You need to start over and understand some basic concepts of C before you start writing code.  You're writing code way beyond your level of understanding.  Go find a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie's book and read it.  You will know what you did wrong before you're halfway through it.  [The book](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass them around as parameters, you can just access them from anywhere (hence global, well as long as you can see the variable).

Any modifications made to those variables are visible to everyone (aside from multithreading issues) so you have no trouble using them in your functions and in main as well.

Comment: I'd like to not use global ones, but I'm not entirely sure how in this case.  I am not quite grasping how to properly pass variables between main and other functions.  The problem is, if I don't declare the variables as global, then main won't allow the compile to continue since the variables are not declared within main (but are in other functions.  See what I mean, take a look at my program again...  Other than this, the program works just fine as I expect it to.  This is my final challenge...

Comment: You just pass them as parameters to functions

Comment: and in the case that you need to modify the values just pass a pointer to the value and use that.

Comment: and if the values are modified in one of the functions that they are passed to as pointers, do they need to be returned as pointers too?

Comment: no you don't need to return the pointer you just modify the value and when the function returns the value that it was change to should be there

Comment: returned as a pointer though or just normally (i.e. not as a pointer)?

Comment: You don't have to return it at all, it could be a function like void my_fun(int *a) { *a = 5; }, if you pass a pointer to any int it will set the value to 5 without needing to return the value.

Comment: ok, so the only way I can see this working is if I declare all of the variables in main, then add them in any function prototypes within my header file and finally to add them to the function the needs them also.  does this effectively get rid of global variables?

Comment: Yes. The functions need a way of "seeing" those variable somehow and passing a pointer is effectively the same (with some caveats of course, function can now modify the contents of the variable, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass global variables because global variables have global [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29), that is they can be accessed anywhere. This is **VERY BAD** programming practice because it may introduce side-effects later in the program when you decide to use the same name for another purpose for example.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) for details.